# How to call a class function in background when ionic app is completely closed?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using Ionic local notification plugin to display notification alert.

Logic behind this is my function is directly connected with firebase database.

As any new record updates in firebase database, this function immediately alerts a notification.

It is working perfectly while my app is active or in background mode. but as i close my application, then this function doesn't work and firebase connectivity also getting lost.

Please suggest me any solutions to keep firebase connection active when application is closed?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to implement push notifications for this purpose.

Comment: @AltafShaikh thnx for ur reply, but i am sending notification alert with specific data as users. is it possible in push notification?

Comment: Yes. You can send data with push notifications.Check this FCM doc to send payload with notification- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Comment: **@AltafShaikh** thnq again sir ...